# Kali Linux Install VB macbook

Tags: linux, kali-linux, installation

I downloaded the kali-linux-2018.4-amd64.iso and ran the graphical install on virtualbox on my mac.

After the install I was able to login and I saw all the tools available, but when I poweroff from terminal and try to restart the machine I get this screen.

I'm super new to linux and am considering CEH as an alternative to my dayjob.

Please help. Thank You

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be an Info Sec question, this might suit another community.

Comment: *"I'm super new to linux"* - then Kali is [**not** the Linux distribution for you](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)  : `... Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.

Even for experienced Linux users, Kali can pose some challenges. ...`